# Can I use older source books for Vampire the Masquerade 5th edition?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

I have been interested in Vampire the Masquerade for quite a while, having first come into interest about it in a small D&D discord group. I've collected many books over a small amount of time before coming into possession of the new edition of Vampire the Masquerade. Now, as I've never played, I find myself slightly confused as to which books I can actually use that I've collected?

The books I've collected are:

- Guide to the Camarilla (1999)
- Clanbook Gangrel (1993)
- Ghouls Fatal Addiction(1997)
- Vampire Storyteller's Companion (1998)
- Clanbook Ventrue (1994)
- Clanbook Tremere (1994)
- Clanbook Toreador (1994)
- Clanbook Malkavian (????)
- Clanbook Brujah (1992)
- Clanbook Nosferatu (1997)
- The Hunters Hunted (1992)
- The Storytellers Handbook (1992)
- Storyteller's Handbook to the Sabbat (1993)
- The Player's Guide to the Sabbat (1992)

Answer (score 6):

You can use all of them. However, mechanically speaking, the games are different enough as to where anything pre-5th ed. is incompatible with that game. Setting-wise, there is a definite tone-shift away from the infamous "dark superheroes" style of game to something more like the current Chronicles of Darkness' prescribed "emotional horror" style.

As a result, the Jyhad and the everlasting war between the Camarilla and the Sabbat is downplayed extensively. The new Hunger sub-system is a particular source of this change on both counts.

However, you can easily refocus the game back to a V20-style and earlier type of setting simply by just using the lore as is in those sourcebooks you have bought and ignoring any mechanical concerns, house-ruling as and when you need.

In short: it's not a big deal, you'll be fine — don't worry!

Comment: I largely agree. It might be worth noting that superficially the two systems look the same (that is to say, pools of D10s, stats + attributes, etc) or at least similar enough to give the impression that they might be compatible.Also, given the majority of the source books are largely narrative in scope, then by and large you can mine them for ideas with no issues but given the setting has shifted in both tone and details, you need to consider them as sources of ideas not source material to be used straight.

Comment: What might be important as well: When it comes to Clan Books or Guides, lots of the lore you'll find there can easily function as backstory - what you read in the "Guide to the Sabbat" or "Clanbook Toreador" then tells you what the situation was like in the 90s. Then you can just add the new lore on top. (If you don't want to use it, @SevenSidedDie already gave a solution) There are some discrepancies, but ... probably nobody will notice or care.